# jQuery - Replace text with text plus html element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some text I wish to replce using jquery. the problem is, is that this text is not within it's own element, the content is dynamic and I can not access HTML the markup to make things easier.

I can detect and replace the text in question, but I have only managed to replace it with a new text node, therefore it treats my html tags as text and not markup

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/XvTgP/

```
$('div.myDiv').contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).each(function () {
    this.textContent = this.textContent.replace('my old text no in its own element', '<div class="newClass">my new text</div>');
    var myNewNode = this.textContent;
    return
});
```

CURRENT OUTPUT AS TEXT

```
<div class="newClass">my new text</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the textNode with the DIV using `replaceWith()`

```
$($('div.myDiv div').get(0).nextSibling).replaceWith('<div class="newClass">my new text</div>');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XvTgP/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `html` when you assign the HTML content:

```
$('div.myDiv').contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).each(function () {
    this.textContent.html = this.textContent.replace('my old text no in its own element', '<div class="newClass">my new text</div>');
    var myNewNode = this.textContent;
    return
});
```

I think you can simplify a bit more:

```
$('div.myDiv').contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).each(function () {
    this.html(this.textContent.replace('my old text no in its own element', '<div class="newClass">my new text</div>'));
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle showing that it works:  http://jsfiddle.net/XvTgP/5/

Answer (score 0):

if i correctly understand question

```
$('div.myDiv').contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).each(function () {
    this.textContent = this.textContent.replace('my old text no in its own element', '<div class="newClass">my new text</div>');
    var myNewNode = this.textContent;
    var myParentNode = myNewNode.parent();
    myParentNode.append(myNewNode);
    return
});
```